# Laptop has no fn lock, what script will make my function keys work like there is a fn lock?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm a beginner at writing scripts and I can't seem to get one that works.
All I want to do is make it so that when I hit F1, it does the equivalent of pressing fn+F1, and so on with all the function keys so I can control my laptop's volume and brightness with a single press.

Can anybody help me out?

I use Windows 10 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

On most Laptops, you can set a parameter in the **BIOS that controls the behaviour of the Function keys** (with or without using the Fn Key). I would check out how to enter the BIOS setup and change this there.

The Fn Key is NOT supported in AutoHotKey, so if you don't change this in the BIOS, you have to program each Function key (as opposed to how the BIOS is set) but that means that you have to program each Function key twice in order not to loose the original function (F1=Help, F2=Edit, F3=Search again, F4=Close, etc.):

e.g.

```
$F4: ; $ to prevent the hotkey (+F4) from triggering this hotkey (F4)
SoundSet,+1 ; Increase Volume with one step
Return

+F4::
Sendinput, {F4} ; Shift F4 now performs the function of F4
Return
```